# Abençôe, abençõe ou abençoe?

Tags: ortografia

Qual é a palavra correta, com acento no circunflexo, til ou sem acento?

- abençôe
- abençõe
- abençoe

Answer (score 2):

A forma correta é [abençoe](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-aben%C3%A7oar), conjugação do verbo abençoar. O uso do til está incorreto pois a palavra não tem som nasal.

Answer (score -3):

Abençoe!  Do verbo *abençoar*:

> Eu te abençôo.

Aí sim é usado o acento circunflexo.

Comment: Nem por isso. Temos ["abençoo"](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aben%C3%A7oo), e não "abençôo".

Comment: [Verbo Abençoar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-aben%C3%A7oar)